# Unable to connect to MQ using IBMXMSDotnetClient .NET Core app

Tags: .net, .net-core, ibm-mq, xms

I am unable to make a successful connection to my IBM MQ. The approach is to connect to MQ without client installation from a .net core app running on Windows 7 machine. I have added nuget package  `IBMXMSDotnetClient` as listed on the ibm website of how to.

I am getting an error `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. The version of nuget is 9.1.4 and the version of MQ is 9.1

Note: I have been successfully able to connect using .net framework code.

```
factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "xyz.com");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "XYZ1");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, 0);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "D:\\SSL\\xyz"); //Path to kdb file
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "XYZChannel");
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AMQ_SSL_ALLOW_DEFAULT_CERT", "1");
```

Comment: cms keystores do not work with managed mode.  Same with `AMQ_SSL_ALLOW_DEFAULT_CERT`

Comment: Can you guide on how I can connect if not for keystore mechanism?

Comment: For the original managed mode with .net framework it used the windows key store `*SYSTEM` or `*USER`. Not sure about core.

Comment: ok, let me try out. Thanks @JoshMc

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work with `*SYSTEM` or `*USER` ?

Comment: no, this isn't working however I try